# Confused about __import__ in Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I trying to import module by `__import__` like this:

```
>>> mod = __import__('x.y.z')
```

But I only got `x`:

```
>>> print mod
>>> <module 'x' from '...'>
```

How should I do to import `z` ? I tried like this, it works but i don't know why.

```
>>> mod = __import__('x.y.z', {}, {}, [''])
>>> print mod
>>> <module 'x.y.z' from '...'>
```

I'm really confused about this, and I also have no idea with the `globals` and `locals` parameters.

Thx a lot!

Comment: Will the module names be variables? If they are strings like here, just use plain `import` instead.

Comment: We can't answer your question on globals and locals until you provide an example where you're having a problem.

Comment: I need to loads a module and all its submodules from a given module path, and the second one works well, from the docs `(__import__)`, `when a non-empty fromlist argument is given, the module named by name is returned.` I think this was a way to solve my problem. thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relevant notes [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) (`__import__`):

> When the name variable is of the form package.module, normally, the top-level package (the name up till the first dot) is returned, not the module named by name. However, when a non-empty fromlist argument is given, the module named by name is returned.

Hence, it's similar to writing `import x.y.z` which also makes `x` available (as well as `x.y` and `x.y.z`).

Comment: `when a non-empty fromlist argument is given, the module named by name is returned.` Maybe that's why the second one works well, thx!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `importlib` module instead. Of which the bare bones are made available in 2.7.

```
import importlib
z = importlib.import_module("z", "x.y") 
# equivalent to
from x.y import z
```